# POST request to SEO URL Forbidden

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a basic MVC system that is sending POST data to URLs such as

admin/product/add/

But this is giving me an error

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access
>   /admin/product/add/ on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

The RewriteRule is simply

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?uri=$1
```

Last time I saw this on a server changing file/directory permissions to 755 seemed to fix it but not this time.  I have never really understood the reason for the error so was hoping someone may be able to provide some more information?

Comment: Are you passing anything with `>` or `<` characters through the form? Alternatively, are any of the form fields named "info"?

Comment: do any rewritten urls work? i.e. is it just this one case, or all urls?

Comment: I am using CKEditor, I thought that encoded html tags but could check.  I will try an area that just posts a basic text field too to see if there is a link.  The rewritten urls work, the add page displays fine

Comment: Besides the rewrite, is there a real directory "admin" on the file system?

Comment: I am 99% certain this is also linked to CKEditor in some way, i've gone back over to TinyMCE and i'll see how that goes

Comment: The ErrorDocument message suggests that it is Apache that is forbidding access to `/admin/product/add`, not your app. Therefore the permission error indicates, as @fab suggests, that you have a real `/admin/product/add` directory in the file system and Apache is blocking access to that prior to reaching the RewriteRule. Access would be blocked because it is a directory and directory listings are denied. Alternately, elsewhere in the Apache configuration all or part of that path is either implicitly denied or not explicitly allowed. There is nothing in the RewriteRule that should cause issues.

Comment: are you posting any large files in your form?

Comment: Is there a `RewriteCond` for that `RewriteRule`? If there isn't, that rewrite rule contradicts almost all the feedback you were given. My assumption is that your routing logic is somehow flawed. Is the `.htaccess` and the `index.php` file in the same directory? Are you overriding `.htaccess` rules, with another .htaccess in a subdirectory named `admin` ?

Answer (score 9):

You have 2 errors:

1. You don't have permission to access /admin/product/add/ on this server.
2. Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

The 2nd one is quite certainly a consequence of the same bug. You may have something in your apache configuration which remove 404 errors from default http server handling and push it to your php application, if this php application was working we would have a nice 404, but...

The first one tells you your php application is not running at all.

So. This first error tell us that apache did try to directly access the directory `/path/to/documentroot/admin/product/add/` on your server and to produce a listing of it (well a listing of the directory content would be done only if apache were authorized to do so). But of course this is not a real directory on your server. It is a **virtual path** in your application. So apache ends up with a 404 (which leads to error 2).

The application handles a **virtual** path, apache does not manage it. The RewriteRule job is to catch the requested path **before** apache is trying to serve it and give it to one single php file (`index.php`) as a query string argument.

So... this rewrite rule was not applied. Things that could prevent this rule to be applied are numerous:

1. mod_rewrite not activated: is the module present and enabled (`RewriteEngine on`)?
2. syntax error: mod rewrite syntax is quite hard to read, sometimes really complex. But here it seems quite simple.
3. The RewriteRule resulting file is maybe not a valid target for apache. If the index.php file is not present in the DocumentRoot, or not readable by the apache user, then apache will fail. **Warning**: having a file readable by the apache user means having read rights on the file but also **execution** rights on all  **parents directories** for the apache user. This is where your classical `chmod`/`chown` solutions are fixing the problems.
4. The rule must be in a valid configuration file. Is this rule in a an apache configuration file, inside a Location or Directory section? Or maybe in the global scope -- this may alter the rewrite Rule syntax--. Or is it in a .htaccess file? If it's a .htacces does apache reads the .htacces files and are mod-rewrite instructions allowed there (`AllowOverride None`). Isn't there others .htaccess files taking precedence?

So to fix the problem:

- If you have an apache version greater than 2.2.16 you can replace the RewriteRule by **[FallbackRessource /index.php](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource)** to check that this does not come from a mod-rewrite problem.
- try to **directly** request `index.php`, so that at least a direct request to this file does work
- try to **directly access a valid ressource** on the documentRoot (a txt file, an image, something that should not be handled by the rewrite but directly served)
- check that if any of your virtual paths could map real physical paths Apache is not trying to serve the physical one (like when you write a `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}-d`) but really push the path to `index.php`
- check apache error **logs**.
- **debug** mod_rewrite with `RewriteLog` and `RewriteLogLevel`
- collect facts, settings and tests, and then push that to SO or [Servfault](http://serverfault.com).

So the problem is quite simple: the php application is not receiving the request. But there are a very big number of ways to end in this state. The message in itself is not very important. The only way to find the error is to check all parameters (or to have years of bug fixing experience and developing a pre-cognitive intuition organ for lamp bugs -- usually a beard --, like admins). And the only way for us to help you is to find strange facts in a big list of configuration details, this is why good questions contains a lot of informations, even if all theses informations looks simply "classical" for you.

**EDIT**

To clarify the problem you should edit your answer, track the `POST` requests with tools such as Chrome developpers tools or firebug (keep the network tracking in record mode to catch several POSTS) or try to replay the post with Live HTTP headers reply. You should try to isolate the problematic POST and give us details. Debug is not magical.

Now I know one magical random POST failure. It's the empty **GET url bug**. It could be that (or not). If you have one empty GET url hidden somewhere (`<IMG SRC="">`, `url()` in css, or an empty LINK in headers for example. As theses hidden POST are defined in HTTP as "replay-the-request-which-launched-the-source-page, and some browsers even replay the POST that gives you the page if they found one. This could lead to broken hidden POSTS.

It could be also that the POST is not sent to the right server. Hard to say. So please collect informations from your comments, add some more network analysis and edit the question which is now really containing not enough facts.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. To clarify a couple of details, the URL works without fail on the without POST data, it loads the blank form to enter all the data which is then POSTed back to itself (action="") which is when the error, intermittently, occurs!  It's the intermittent part which is causing the real headache.  The POST data did include CKEditor text (which I know isn't the same as the HTML view, it does some processing) and URLs in standard text input boxes.  Reverting to TinyMCE has made it go away but it's very frustrating not knowing why.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =POST
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?uri=$1
```

Comment: I'm not a htaccess expert but won't that just limit the rewrite to conditions where post data exists?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?uri=$1 [L]
```

Also use only www or non-www domain but not both at the same time. Redirect users with htaccess where you would like like to...

NonWWW to WWW:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

WWW to NonWWW:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^www\.(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```